# Expand the date and insert into another table

Tags: sql, oracle

Need to expand this second row of table part
and insert into table fct table.
Table 1:- Part
Table 2:- fct
do not depend on A column  and B column will in a form in query is b like '%MT'

```
 Part 
    
    a       b           c           d           e       f     g     
    
    600   MT_000        6765    29-04-22    30-04-22    1   WEEK
          MT            6758    01-05-22    31-05-22    1   MONTH
    601   MT_0001       6771    01-06-22    30-06-22    1   WEEK
    
    


want like this
```

FCT

```
 a      b               c       d            e              f       g   
  600      MT_000               6765    30-04-22    30-04-22    1   WEEK
           MT           6758    01-05-22    07-05-22    1   MONTH
        MT          6758    08-05-22    14-05-22    1   MONTH      
        MT          6758    15-05-22    21-05-22    1   MONTH      
        MT          6758    22-05-22    28-05-22    1   MONTH      
        MT          6758    29-05-22    31-05-22    1   MONTH   
        MT          6758    01-06-22    02-06-22    1   WEEK
```

Comment: _second row_ - according to what order?

Comment: weekly wish as in first PART table its in monthly wise, Can use intermediatate table

Comment: Expand in what way? Please imagine yourself a person who is out of *your* context and explain the rules in general words. Like "take row 2 in the above dataset, add <1,2,3> and calculate <4,5,6>"

Comment: See we have one row in table "part" which is in month level means it has data of starting of the month and ending of the month date as mentioned 01-05-22 and 31-05-22 and as value "month" so we need to expand this row and insert it into "FCT" table all the values will be same just need what that to expand that monthly data into weekly form and requirement what i want data should look like mentioned above

Comment: not clear please ask me more

Comment: Do you mean you want to break a (full?) month row into several rows, each one for a calendar week?

Comment: Yes correct ....

Comment: What do you mean by "expand the date"?

Comment: Then the question should be updated: for each (or for rows based on some condition) you need to generate 1 week intervals, where the first interval starts at date in the column `d` and the last interval ends on the date of column `e`. Also note that some columns look irrelevant for the question and should be removed (or their role should be described, see [How to create a **Minimal**, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply recursive subquery producing weeks to month-type rows like here:

```
select a, b, c, case g when 'MONTH' then d1 else d end d, least(d2, e) e, f, g
from fct
cross apply (
  select trunc(d, 'mm') + (level - 1) * 7 d1, trunc(d, 'mm') + level * 7 - 1 d2
  from dual 
  connect by g = 'MONTH' and trunc(d, 'mm') + (level - 1) * 7 <= e )
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/00l-Sisz)